# Add user edit fields to pane

Tags: users, panels

I have a pane on a Dashboard page that's supposed to be an accordion.

It's supposed to update user information. I still haven't figured out how can I add user fields inside this pane, for example:

Update your information:

Name      _______

Password  _______

E-mail    _______

etc.

Is that possible? Do I have to use a preprocess function to add that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module in drupal called [Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) . This module will allow you to present many forms through blocks . [Advanced Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb) is another module with same goal .

if these modules couldn't help you can do it by yourself .
create a module , [create your own form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/group/form_api/7) , your form callback can be [User save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7) , export your form as a block .